Taking derivative to determine differentiability
The "correct" way to determine differentiability is to use the definition of the derivative as a limit. However, sometimes we have a function with a piecewise definition. Say for example (just an example, the question itself is more general)
$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
e^x & x\leq 0\\
{\sin x} & x>0 \end{cases}$
A "shortcut" is to take the derivative of both pieces of the function at the "breaking point" $x=c$ and take the right hand and left hand limits of the derivatives as x approaches c. However, their equality does not always imply that the function is differentiable. In the above case this would not work: the limits of the derivatives of both parts are 1, but the function itself is not differentiable at $x=0$ because it is not continuous at the point. So it is only differentiable in the neighbourhood of x=0 but not at 0 itself.
However, if the function above were continuous, say we had $(\sin x)+1$ instead, it would be differentiable at x=0.
It seems that continuity of f at x=0 was the "missing piece" to making it differentiable.
So my question is, do the equality of the limits of the derivatives of $f$ from both sides of $x=c$, AND the continuity of $f$ at $c$, together imply that the function is differentiable at x=c? If yes can we prove it?

I can see how the left-handed derivative is 1, but the right-handed derivative is not 1. Remember that this right-hand derivative uses the function value at 0: $\lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{sin(h)-1}{h}$ which doesn't exist (is infinite).

In general, if you can prove the left and right limits are equal ($\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$), then it's differentiable at $x$, but this isn't possible for the original function you give.

Perhaps your ultimate claim takes this form:
If:

$f$ is known to be differentiable when $x\ne c$,
$f'(x)\to L$ as $x\to c$,
$f$ is continuous at $c$,

then $f$ is differentiable at $c$ as well.
This is true.
By the Mean Value Theorem (since $f$ is appropriately continuous and differentiable), there is an $x_0$ between $c$ and $c+h$ such that $\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}=f'(x_0)$. As $h\to 0$, we'd have $x_0\to c$ (since $x_0$ is between $c$ and $c+h$), so $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h} = \lim_{x_0\to c} f'(x_0) = L$. This shows that $f$ is differentiable at $c$, and $f'(c)=L$ as well.
